# Cant cast custom control

Tags: c#, custom-controls, controls, ribbon

I am attempting to use a Custom Ribbon panel, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25907/A-Professional-Ribbon-You-Will-Use-Now-with-orb, as well as working out a way to make a application that will take "Plugin" .dll's. 
This is the code that I am trying at the moment.

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"dir");
        Type type = assembly.GetType("WindowsFormsControlLibrary2.UserControl1");
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        string s = "GiveControl";
        UserControl uc = (UserControl)type.GetMethod(s).Invoke(o, null);
        ((Panel)uc.Controls.Find("panel1", true)[0]).Parent = panel2;

        RibbonTab rt = (RibbonTab)uc.Controls.Find("ribbonTab1", true)[0];
```

The last line is giving me an error that states "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RibbonTab'"

Its obvious what this message means, but I don't understand why it is happening. Is there a reason that custom controls can't be found this way?

This code/application is just a proof of concept/trying to find a way to do this (My first attempt).
Any known ways to do this would be appreciated.

------UPDATE------
Appologies, I should have said, this error is happening at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: I would debug and see what kinda control that find is getting make sure it is the RibbonTab control

Comment: See comment on "Reed Copsey" answer

Comment: I realized this is happening at runtime, Reed Copsey and I have come to the same conclusion, the control you are trying to cast might not be a ribbontab

Comment: This is happening at Compile time. Not runtime. Visual Studio doesnt see it as a control.

Comment: my bad I miss read what you said sorry! See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because RibbonTab is not a control

```
public class RibbonTab : Component, IRibbonElement, IContainsRibbonComponents
```

Comment: Technically correct, so i will check this as the answer. Thanks to Reed Copsey aswell

Answer (score 2):

Your code *should* work, provided the returned control is actually a `System.Windows.Forms.RibbonTab`.

However, at runtime, it's not.  You can rework your code to make it easier to diagnose.  Instead of writing:

```
RibbonTab rt = (RibbonTab)uc.Controls.Find("ribbonTab1", true)[0];
```

I would break it up and do some error checking:

```
Control controls[] = uc.Controls.Find("ribbonTab1", true);
if (controls.Length == 0)
{
   // No "ribbonTab1" control was found - 
}   

Control rtControl = controls[0];
RibbonTab rt = rtControl as RibbonTab;
if (rt == null)
{
    // The first control named "ribbonTab1" wasn't actually a ribbon tab...
    // Check rtControl.GetType() to see what type it is actually defined to be
}
```

Comment: See update. 
Just put your code in. The uc.Controls.Find("ribbonTab1") is bringing back nothing. For some reason, the Application is seeing the not seeing the RibbonTab as a control. There is also now a link to the controls that I using in the question.

Comment: @Seige Are you finding the panels? etc?  Why not just create a new control directly?

Comment: Yes, i made it just to see if it got the controls (No casting), and the panel is still displaying on the form. The control list is just empty. What i am trying to achieve, is a application that when a "plugin" dll is placed next to it, it is incorperated into the app. Including design and code. Sorry having internet problems.

Comment: @Seige Why not use MEF to dynamically load your "plugin" and just expose a `Control` to add directly?  Far simpler...

Comment: Because i dont know about other ways of doing things like this. Thats why i tagged that little bit at the end of my question :) I am open to ideas. I will look into MEF, thanks.

Comment: It seems that RibbonTab doesnt like being called a Control. However, its parent, the Ribbon, does. So to get to the Tab, I have pulled out the Ribbon, and through that have access to the RibbonTab..